# column-wise exception from a standard method (eg. mean, sum, first) for groupby possible?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is my first question, hope I have done things right.

I have a dataframe with 50+ columns that I want to use groupby on. 
All columns except for one should be grouped using `first()`.
The remaining column should be grouped by `mean()`.

This is part of the dataframe `df`

```
df = df.iloc[:10,:8]

   id_x first_name country_x  sex  height  weight  score
0     1       Leif       SWE    0     177      73     100.0             
1     1       Leif       SWE    0     177      73     112.0             
2     1       Leif       SWE    0     177      73     98.0             
3     1       Leif       SWE    0     177      73     73.5             
4     1       Leif       SWE    0     177      73     50.0             
5     3     Magnus       SWE    0     180      78     45.5             
6     3     Magnus       SWE    0     180      78     72.0             
7     3     Magnus       SWE    0     180      78     83.5             
8     3     Magnus       SWE    0     180      78     95.0             
9     3     Magnus       SWE    0     180      78     115.0
```

As I understood I could do a groupby with different methods applied for each column by using 
`df.groupby('id_x').agg()` 
using a dictionary with the required method for each column, but this would be a rather long dictionary.

So is there a way to group and use a standard method and an exception for one (or n) columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary might be long, but you can create it succinctly with a dict comprehension. Use `first` for everything not the grouping column or your special column(s), then add your special column with `'mean'`

```
d = {x: 'first' for x in df.columns.difference(['id_x', 'score'])}
d['score'] = 'mean'

df.groupby('id_x').agg(d)
#     country_x first_name  height  sex  weight  score
#id_x                                                 
#1          SWE       Leif     177    0      73   86.7
#3          SWE     Magnus     180    0      78   82.2
```

Comment: Many thanks for quick reply and solving the problem! Unfortunately I cannot upvote due to low reputation.

Comment: No worries, it was a clear question so I'm happy to help! Happy coding :D